# Proper way to overlay multiband images?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I want to overlay two views of the same scene - one is a white-light image (monochrome, used for reference) and the other is an image in a specific band (that has the real data I'm showing).

The white-light image is "reference", the data image is "data". They're ordinary 2D numpy arrays of identical dimensions.  I want to show the white reference image using the 'gray' color map, and the data image using the 'hot' color map.

What is the "proper" way to do this?

I started with this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

hotm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='hot')
graym = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='gray')

ref_rgb  = graym.to_rgba(reference) # rgba reference image, 'gray' color map
data_rgb = hotm.to_rgb(data) # rgba data image, 'hot' color map

plt.imshow(ref_rgb + data_rgb)
```

That didn't work well because in the `plt.imshow()` call the sum overflowed the range 0..1 (or maybe 0..255; this is confusing) and gave me crazy colors.

Then I replaced the last line with this:

```
plt.imshow(ref_rgb/2 + data_rgb/2)
```

That worked, but gives me a very washed-out, low-contrast image.

Finally, I tried this:

```
plt.imshow(np.maximum(ref_rgb, data_rgb))
```

That seems to give the best result, but I'm worried that much of my "data" is lost by having lower r, g, or b values than the reference image.

What is the "proper", or "usual" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully this will give you some ideas. :)

I've never used matplotlib, but from a quick look at the docs, it looks like matplotlib.cm gives you the option to have the pixel data as integers in the 0..255 range or as floats in the 0.0..1.0 range. The float format is more convenient for arithmetic image processing, so I'll assume that's the case in the rest of this answer.

We can do basic image processing by doing simple arithmetic on the RGB pixel values. Roughly speaking, adding (or subtracting) a constant to the RGB value of all your pixels changes the image brightness, multiplying your pixels by a constant changes the image contrast, and raising your pixels to a constant (positive) power changes the image gamma. Of course, you do need to make sure that these operations don't cause the colour values to go out of range. That's not a problem for gamma adjustment, or contrast adjustment (assuming the constant is in the 0.0..1.0 range), but it can be a problem for brightness modification. More subtle brightness & contrast modification can be achieved by suitable combinations of addition and multiplication.

When doing this sort of thing it's often a Good Idea to normalize the pixel values in your image data to the 0.0..1.0 range, either before &/or after you've done your main processing.

Your code above is essentially treating the grey reference data as a kind of mask and using its values, instead of using a constant, to operate on the colour data pixel by pixel. As you've seen, taking the mean of ref_rgb & data_rgb results in a washed-out image because you are reducing the contrast. But see what happens when you multiply ref_rgb & data_rgb: contrast will generally be increased because dark areas in ref_rgb will darken the corresponding pixels in data_rgb but bright areas in ref_rgb will leave the corresponding pixels in data_rgb virtually untouched.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#math) has some nice examples of arithmetic image processing.

Another thing to try is to convert your data_rgb to HSV format, and replace the V (value) data with the greyscale data from ref_rgb. And you can do similar tricks with the S (saturation) data, although the effect is generally a bit subtler.